# Make loop stop by pressing dot

Tags: c

I need to write a program that asks you to enter numbers and when you press dot it will end the loop and  display how many numbers are positive and how many are negative,  like for example 4  5  -9  .

The program should show 2 numbers are positive and 1 is negative,  but that isn't my problem. I'm stuck at the part where the loop should stop when I press dot, and bear in mind we are at the starter ages of programming so I can't be using fancy stuff.

As you can see here I tried giving a variable two types (`char` and `float`) but that doesn't work I think because it uses the value of the character instead of the numbers themselves.

```
int main()
{
    float p, n;
    char a;

    n = 0;
    p = 0;

    do
    {
        printf("type a number");
        scanf("%s&%f", &a);

        if (a < 0)
        {
            n = n + 1;
        }
        else if (a > 0)
        {
            p = p + 1;
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    while (a != '.');

    printf(" positive numbers are %2.0f \n  negative numbers are %2.0f", p, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My edit was to clean up your code indentation, which made it very hard to read (*hint*: do a Google search on C formatting standards). You need to un-mix-up your code a bit. You start by scanning in the `a` variable (where and how did you come up with `"%s&%f"` as a scan format string and what do you think it means? - did you read the `scanf` documentation?). Then you are comparing it with `0` before you even know if it's a number entered by the user. You need to (1) read the input, (2) determine if it's a number and convert if it is, or exit if it's `'.'`.

Comment: For counting, you should use integers (`int` or a variant on it), rather than `float`.  You probably want to read numbers (are the numbers entered going to be integers or can they be floating point?) until the `scanf()` says "that wasn't a number".  It would do that when you enter a `.`; it would also do it when you type `albatross`, or if you indicate EOF. (Note that this avoids issues with "what to do when what is entered is neither a number nor a `.`".) Then you can print your totals.  Are you supposed to ignore zero when it is entered? If not, add `int z = 0;` and `else z++;` and print it.

Comment: @lurker yes  obviosly my code is not right or else i wouldnt be posting it here, the "%s&%f"  was just  to see if whatever i type will be  concidered as a character and  a number and be used accordingly  but i know it's wrong and yes i need a way to make it read what i type and then determine if its a character or a  float  . is there a way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code through the popular online c compiler here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php

Your code ran as expected. What happens when you type "."?

EDIT: (Solution)

The problem was that when you input a negative number,

```
a = '-'
```

which has an integer value greater than zero, hence not triggering the negative case.

The solution then, is to check for the negative sign:

```
if (a == '-') {...}
```

Also, note that the '.' entered to terminate the loop is being counted as a positive number.

Answer (score 0):

You should just read the input into a string and convert it to an integer if the first character isn't a '.'.  Something like this:

```
    printf("type a number\n");
    scanf("%s", a);
    if (a[0] == '.') {
        break;
    }
    i = strtoul(a, NULL, 10);
```

Then you can see if i is positive or negative.  Declare a as a char[10] or something.

Comment: is there a way to replace  i = strtoul(a, NULL, 10); wth something else less advanced

Comment: i = atoi(a) would be the equivalent.  They both convert ASCII strings to integers

Comment: should i declare i as intiger, and is there a type of library header i should use

Comment: if you do a lookup on atoi you'd see what you need to know.  it's a standard c function that is defined in stdlib.h and returns an int.